# cant get menu to work

Tags: php, mysql

So I have created a menu but I can't get the link to the pages to work.
In PHPmyadmin I have a table called **menus**.

In the table you can find the **ID, Name, parentid** (for submenus) and **href** (those fields contain just the page name like index.php/news.php etc.)

```
   <?php include 'assets/class/dbcon.php'; ?>

<?php
    function loop_array($array = array(), $parent_id = 0){
        $html = 'http://mywebsite.com/';
            global $connection; 
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT href FROM menus");
            $href = Array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $href = $row['href'];

            }
        if(!empty($array[$parent_id])){

            echo '<ul class="cssmenu">';
            foreach($array[$parent_id] as $items){
            echo '<a href="'.$html.$href.'"><li style="z-index: 100;">';
            echo $items['name'];
            loop_array($array, $items['id']);
            echo '</li></a>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';

        }       
    }

    function display_menus() 
    {


    global $connection;
    $query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM menus");
    $array = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){

        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            $array[$rows['parent_id']][] = $rows;

        }
        loop_array($array);
    }


    }

    mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
```

The idea is that when I click on a li tag,
 that is loads up http://mywebsite.com/variouspages.php but what it does now is when I click on a li tag its sends me back to mywebsite.com. If I echo out the href column it shows all the href links. So it says something like index.phpnews.phpfotos.php

hope that someone can help me with this. Thanks! much love.

Comment: This is a confusing stew of PHP code and HTML. What are you trying to do? Why can't this be separated more?

Comment: `.$html.$href.` what does this mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please check out [ask] for more information on asking good questions.  In this case, it might be helpful to you and the people answering if you can provide a [mcve] illustrating the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

google dev:

```
   <header>
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #383838; border-bottom: 4px solid #cd0000;">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="cssmenu"><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Home</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Nieuws</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"></a><li style="z-index: 100;"><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/">De Marskoppen</a><ul class="cssmenu"><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Foto's</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Agenda</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Het Bestuur</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Historie</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Commissies</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Lid worden</li></a></ul></li><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"></a><li style="z-index: 100;"><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/">Garde Officieren</a><ul class="cssmenu"><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Foto's</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Agenda</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Leden</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Historie</li></a></ul></li><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Vorstenhuis</li></a><a href="http://cvdemarskoppen.nl/"><li style="z-index: 100;">Sponsors</li></a></ul>   </div>
    </div>
        <div class="header">
            <div style="display: none; background-color: #fe0000; width: 30%; float: left; height: 199px; position: absolute; margin: 60px 0 0 0; border-top: 4px solid #3f454b; border-bottom: 4px solid #3f454b;"></div>
            <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
            <div style="display: none; background-image: url('css/images/header/logo.png'); width: 209px; height: 208px; position: absolute; z-index: 4; float: right; margin: -4 0 0 180;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="cycler" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <img class="active" src="css/images/header/1.jpg" alt="Plaats hier een foto." style="width: 100%; height: 150%; margin-top: -10%; display: block; z-index: 3;">
                <img src="css/images/header/2.jpg" alt="Plaats hier een foto." style="width: 100%; height: 150%; margin-top: -10%; z-index: 1; display: block;" class="">   
                <img src="css/images/header/3.jpg" alt="Plaats hier een foto." style="width: 100%; height: 150%; margin-top: -10%; z-index: 1; display: block;" class="">           
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <script>
    function cycleImages(){
          var $active = $('#cycler .active');
          var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
          $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
          $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
              $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
          });
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    // run every 7s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
    })
        </script>

    </header>
```

Html i wrote for the menu.

```
<header>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: #383838; border-bottom: 4px solid #cd0000;">
    <div class="menu">
        <?php display_menus(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks for your help. keep in mind, this is trial and error for me. New to php so i'm still learning everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your link is being assembled incorrectly because you aren't looping through the values of the `href` array to append to the `html` variable.

You are only looping through `$array[$parent_id]` and then trying to append the `$href` array (not it's values) to the `$html` variable thereafter.

This essentially gives you `http://mywebsite.com/array` or just simply `http://mywebsite.com/` in the DOM.

You need to add a loop for the `$html` array as follows:

```
$html = 'http://mywebsite.com/';

$href = array('a', 'b', 'c'); //this comes from your db as per your question

$link = '';
$link .= '<ul>';

foreach($href as $val){
    $link .= '<a href="' . $html . $val . '"><li style="z-index: 100;"></li></a>';
}

$link .= '</ul>';
echo $link;
```

This will give you the following in the DOM:

```
<ul>
 <a href="http://mywebsite.com/a"><li style="z-index: 100;"></li></a>
 <a href="http://mywebsite.com/b"><li style="z-index: 100;"></li></a>
 <a href="http://mywebsite.com/c"><li style="z-index: 100;"></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: i see sort off what you mean. But i cant really place the placement of the code. And the a b c you mean the .php files? or the colums. here a image of the databse build up https://gyazo.com/dfd8b2cda8cbd1b8f02ba22c985a9056

Comment: I used "a,b, & c" for the example code, but these are your .php files sourced from your db to add onto `$html`. You would need to refactor your code to obtain the `href` values . There are a few ways this can be done, you could even use `array_pop()` inside first foreach loop to get the last value of `href` each time, and append it to `$html`